# Using HttpRequestHandlerServlet in programatically configured Jetty embedded server

Tags: java, spring, jetty, spring-remoting, httpinvoker

I have programatically defined a Jetty server and added an instance of a HttpRequestHandlerServlet.  I am trying to do all of this without a web.xml file.  Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.springframework.context.support.StaticApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet;

public class TestServer extends Server {

    public TestServer() throws Exception {      
        super(8888);

        final ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(this, "/", ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS|ServletContextHandler.NO_SECURITY);
        final ServletContext context = contextHandler.getServletContext();

        StaticApplicationContext applicationContext = new StaticApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.registerSingleton("testServlet", TestBean.class);
        applicationContext.refresh();

        GenericWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
        webApplicationContext.setParent(applicationContext);
        webApplicationContext.setServletContext(context);
        webApplicationContext.refresh();

        context.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, webApplicationContext);

        ServletConfig servletConfig = new ServletConfig() {

            @Override
            public String getServletName() {                
                return "testServlet";
            }

            @Override
            public ServletContext getServletContext() {
                return context;
            }

            @Override
            public String getInitParameter(String name) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getInitParameterNames() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        HttpRequestHandlerServlet httpRequestHandlerServlet = new HttpRequestHandlerServlet();
        httpRequestHandlerServlet.init(servletConfig);

        ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(httpRequestHandlerServlet);

        contextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/testBean");

        start();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        TestServer testServer = new TestServer();

        Request baseRequest = new Request();
        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequestWrapper.class);
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponseWrapper.class);

        testServer.handle("/testBean", baseRequest, request, response);     
    }
}

class TestBean implements HttpRequestHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getOutputStream().write("Steve".getBytes());
    }   
}
```

If you run the test, the following exception (root cause) occurs:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet-406774688' is defined
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1108)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:270)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.init(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:58)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:477)

I am using Jetty 7.6.9.v20130131 (due to a dependency in my real project on Camel 2.12.1) and Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Steve Ardis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew that "The target bean name must match the HttpRequestHandlerServlet servlet-name as defined in web.xml" (see the JavaDoc on HttpRequestHandlerServlet), but I was only doing half of what was required when using the programmatic approach.

Adding the following code got me past this issue:

```
servletHolder.setName("testServlet");
```

Steve Ardis